# sidekiq and rails truncate helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, truncate

I'm trying to use the [Rails truncate helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html) inside of Sidekiq.  Everything works fine outside of Sidekiq but inside sidekiq when I try to process the job it gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each_byte' for nil:NilClass
```

This is because Sidekiq contains it's own truncate method:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq/3.3.1/Sidekiq/WebHelpers:truncate

The problem is it's too simple compared to the Rails helper and I need to be able to truncate words as opposed to chars. So I tried to use the method explictly:

```
content = ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper.truncate(content.gsub(/\n/, ''), :length => 126, :separator => ' ', :omission => '', :escape => false)
```

But this still gave me the same error as before.

Additionally, I also tried including the helper in the top of the class

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
```

But that didn't seem to make any difference. Any ideas how I can use the Rails truncate method inside Sidekiq?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Just open source code by your link above `Source: hide | on GitHub`:

```
def truncate(text, options = {}, &block)
  if text
    length  = options.fetch(:length, 30)

    content = text.truncate(length, options) // <--
    content = options[:escape] == false ? content.html_safe : ERB::Util.html_escape(content)
    content << capture(&block) if block_given? && text.length > length
    content
  end
end
```

As you can see this method just using `truncate` [method of String](http://apidock.com/rails/String/truncate). Just use it instead of ActionView helper.